# difference between mysql and mysqldump

Tags: linux, mysql

I am going to importi a database.. (`db.sql`)

I will use something like:

```
mysql -u root -p db < db.sql
```

Can you tell me what the difference is between this and `mysqldump`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysqldump` is the export tool with which you would create the file to import, e.g.

```
mysqldump -u root -p db > db-export.sql
```

The resulting file will consist largely of SQL `CREATE` statements, followed by `INSERT` statements.

`mysql` is the interactive MySQL client, which will also happily take a file full of SQL on `stdin` and carry out those queries -- in this case, importing the exported dump.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump is for export/backup databases:

```
mysqldump -u root -p db > db.sql
```